# Nuxt Link to="" not valid html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

I have noticed that when running my pages through html validation it is flagged that my links have a `to="[object Object]` which is not valid HTML.

I am using Nuxt Links in Nuxt Vue, the `to` is used to provide the link in the code, but this is converted into a href while leaving this when compiled, which seems to serve no purpose:

```
<a href="/home" to="[object Object]">Home</a>
```

Is there a way to remove the `to` from links using Vue Nuxt?

Comment: what's the source? shold be something like `<nuxt-link to="/home">Home</nuxt-link>`?

Comment: you should provide the source code as well (the `<nuxt-link :to ...`), only then we can know what's wrong

Comment: Probably missing the `:to` here since you're passing an object. What do you have in your DOM? Inspect with your devtools to see if the HTML is valid. A nuxt link should compile properly. Otherwise, feel free to share a [repro] + the validator you're using.